# Can I use overlay filesystem on an expanded filesystem?

Tags: pi-3b+, sd-card, filesystem

I've used raspi-config to activate overlay filesystem and made the boot partition read only.  As I was running out of space I decided to use raspi-config to expand the filesystem to fill the entire SD.  After this however I lose the overlay filesystem.  When I reactivate the overlay filesystem it goes back to the original root space which is about 500MB.
Is there a way to expand the filesystem and also activate overlay filesystem to use the expanded space?
Thanks